# CreateFreshAPIToken or Personal Access Token. And does CreateFreshAPIToken work with AJAX?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I am making a API based web application. It will contain various users like normal users, admins with webpages with tables for updating, deleting, showing stuff. There will be obviously many pages and access will depend on scope of user. I am confused and stuck at point that:

Should I generate personal access token with a scope every-time a user logins and use that for checking user's group(if it has permission or not) for giving access to webpages and for making some requests.

OR

Should I use CreateFreshApiToken Middleware for requests and I should just check user's group while logging in to give him access to some webpages.

I hope you understood what I'm trying to say.

And CreateFreshApiToken middleware attaches a laravel_token cookie to outgoing responses. If I'm using AJAX, does that work? If not, does that mean I will always have to pass access token with request?

Comment: // Creating a token with scopes...

```$token = $user->createToken('My Token', ['place-orders', 'create-order','edit-order']])->accessToken;```
did you try this one. add all scope in generate the token.

Comment: @PrashantBarve ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go for the second scenario and use the CreateFreshApiToken Middleware, because scopes are in a certain sense subordinate to the user groups / user rights / user roles in your application.

For example, a user can have the rights to place and view orders once logged in to your application. But, developers of for example a mobile app consuming your API, could decide to only give users logging in to this app rights to view orders, i.e. the `orders.view` scope and not the rights to place orders. Compare this to for example a Google API. As a user of Gmail, you have the rights to read and delete emails, etc. But when you develop an app consuming the Gmail API, you could decide that the app only needs and only will ask the user for the scopes that are needed to read emails.

Managing the whole authorization layer in a Laravel application with scopes is therefore very thin. In most cases it is better to separate the authorization layer of your applications (user roles, rights etc.) with the authorization layer of your API (scopes).

The CreateFreshApiToken middleware is meant for consuming your API with JavaScript and AJAX. The `laravel_token` will be attached as a cookie to each AJAX request after the first GET request that is made to a web route after logging in (a request to `/home` is made automatically by the Laravel Auth scaffolding after login). Description can be found in this part of the Passport documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

Personal Access Tokens can be seen as API keys. API consumers can use this key to authorise with your API, without going through the OAuth2 flow. You would have to create a proxy from your JavaScript application to your API to make requests with this token, which would be very strange.